# Array mapping object key that is quoted

Tags: node.js, arrays

I have this object

```
    let array =  [{
     '@id': 123,
      item: 'Test'
    }]
```

I want to map the @id but I am having an error.

Here is my sample code

```
new Set(array.map(( { '@id' } ) => console.log( '@id' )));
```

it should return from the console

```
123
```

How do I map quoted keys?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference in JS to quote object keys or not.

If you want to map all the array objects and extract the @id, do this:

```
array.map(el=> el['@id'])
```

Output:

```
[123]
```

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, I realized and did this after I posted this question. But thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This will not work since [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for `@id` will not work since there is `@` at the beginning of the variable name and its not valid, this is how you can use map your Array elements:

```
let array = [
  {
    "@id": 123,
    item: "Test",
  },
];

array.map((el) => console.log(el["@id"]));
```